# Thunar says "not authorized to perform this operation" when I try to mount a partition. How can I fix this?

Tags: mount, xubuntu, thunar

I use Thunar and Pcmanfm. Both are displaying the same problem. It was working fine before. Suddenly one day this message appeared. As far as I remember, I've not changed anything knowingly.

Edit 1: Output of `ps -ef | grep pol`

```
root       142     2  0 May10 ?        00:00:00 [edac-poller]
root      1137     1  0 May10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ModemManager --filter-policy=strict
root      1415     1  0 May10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
axeman    2853  2827  0 May10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
axeman    4162  4112  0 00:02 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pol
```

Edit 2: Output of `dpkg -l | grep polk`

```
ii  gir1.2-polkit-1.0                       0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5                          amd64        GObject introspection data for PolicyKit
ii  libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64               0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5                          amd64        PolicyKit Authentication Agent API
ii  libpolkit-backend-1-0:amd64             0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5                          amd64        PolicyKit backend API
ii  libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64             0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5                          amd64        PolicyKit Authorization API
```

Comment: Ensure that you have `noauto,user` in the /etc/fstab` options for that partition.

Comment: that partion has no entry in `/etc/fstab` . Still it mounted without password prompt, when I clicked that partition in Thunar. But now its not saying `not authorized...` error.

Comment: One more thing I noticed is when i'm trying to mount a partition by `gnome-disks` it does well without any error or password prompt.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep pol` and `dpkg -l | grep polk` please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through some other forums, I realized the problem might be somewhat related to `gvfs`. I thought so because `gnome-disks` was working fine. In a post,someone said to check whether the user's current session is active or not.The problem was indeed about sessions.
When I cheked output of `loginctl`, I got:

```
SESSION        UID USER             SEAT             TTY
c3       1000 axeman           seat0                            
c1       1000 axeman                            chrome-remote-desktop
```

So the chrome-remote-desktop session was the cause of all these issues(I installed it some days before). Then I opened chrome and deleted the device profile, which I had created for remote desktop. Now, `loginctl` output showed only one session. After that, I checked Thunar and PCmanFM both and mounting was working as expected.
Note: I re-created the problem and solved it again to make sure that the session created by chrome-remote-desktop was the reason for this issue.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Still I dont understand the exact reason behind it. because the `c3` session was active anyway. Can someone please explain this? What exactly caused the problem?